# Loop through array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I am trying to loop through this array

```
var questions = [
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the best language?',
        correct: 0,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the most popular language?',
        correct: 1,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },

]
```

and the point is I  want to get every question with this loop and get these questions in console log

```
var currentQuestion = questions.length;

for( var i = 0; i < currentQuestion; i++){
   console.log(questions[i]);
}
```

but console.log says: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: I try to reproduce your solution and everything is good. Maybe you didn`t export questions?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the variable questions is not included in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

more information at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects about the js objects.

```js
var questions = [
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the best language?',
        correct: 0,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the most popular language?',
        correct: 1,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },

];

var currentQuestion = questions.length;

for( var i = 0; i < currentQuestion; i++){
   console.log(questions[i].ask);
}

// es6 way 

questions.map(q => {
   // console.log(q.ask); // will get all the questions
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for of.. :

```js
var questions = [
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the best language?',
        correct: 0,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },
    {
        ask: 'is Javascript the most popular language?',
        correct: 1,
        answer : [
            {text: 'yes'},
            {text: 'No'}
        ]
    },

]

for(let values of questions){
  console.log(values);
 }
```